# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - type of items in the drop down list

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that has a ComboBox column. I populate this column's list with items of a type **Field**:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn fieldsColumn = argumentsDataGridView.Columns["field"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            foreach (Field field in SessionData.Fields)
                fieldsColumn.Items.Add(field);
            fieldsColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Then after some user's action I put a value in the cell of this column like this:

```
private void AddArgument(string argumentName, Field field)
        {
            int index = argumentsDataGridView.Rows.Count;
            argumentsDataGridView.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
            DataGridViewRow newRow = argumentsDataGridView.Rows[index];
            newRow.Cells["nameArg"].Value = argumentName;
            -> newRow.Cells["field"].Value = field;
        }
```

If I now access the cell's Value, it is of a type **Field**. If I select different item from the combo, the cell's Value becomes a string. How can I handle it? I need items of type **Field**.

Comment: How are you even getting this to work? When I ran a simple test, I get a System.ArgumentException?

Comment: where are you getting this exception?

Comment: I created a dummy class with three properties. I then created a List of a few of these objects, and added them to the ComboBoxColumn like in your first method. Then, I replicated your second method, by adding another row, and adding another object, but then get an Exception.

Comment: Are you handling the DataError event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to create a property **Self** in class **Field**:

```
public Field Self
        {
            get { return this; }
        }
```

and set is as a ValueMember of the combo box column.
I thought that without specifing ValueMember *this* is a default return value and I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. WPF binding is way better.